# Load JS Function stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString with IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I have a simple javascript function with two variables for the geolocation. I need to pass two variables that I already have in my iOS application to this javascript function.

When I send the code via console in the browser everything is OK:

```
geoCallBackSuccess({coords:{'longitude':9.598470,'latitude':50.903697}})
```

Is my code correct?

In the simulator I see no effect...

```
NSString * param  = @"{coords:{'longitude':9.598470,'latitude':50.903697}}";
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoCallBackSuccess(%@)",param];
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad - jsCallBack: %@", jsCallBack);
[self.offerUrl stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

Log:

> viewDidLoad - jsCallBack:
>   geoCallBackSuccess({coords:{'longitude':9.598470,'latitude':50.903697}})

For example, this works for me:

```
[self.offerUrl  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"anzeige\").innerHTML=\"Hello World\";"];
```

I want to do the same as I do in Android:

```
@java...

public void getLocation() {
// magic
if (locationOk) { 
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:geoCallBackSuccess({coords:{'longitude':9.598470,'latitude':50.903697}})");
} else { webview.loadUrl("javascript:geoCallBackError({code:})");
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing just one semi colon in the string, semicolon after function name -

```
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geoCallBackSuccess(%@);",param];
```